# Is it still genocide if it's everyone but a particular group?

Tags: meaning

a google definition of genocide is

> the deliberate killing of a large group of people, especially those of a particular nation or ethnic group.

but what if the deliberate killing was everyone but those of a particular nation or ethnic group, for instance a religious group who believes their god seeks to purge the world of all life with the exception of the faithful. this also includes other non-human races (elf, drawf, orc, etc) and animals

So would the deliberate killing of everything but a single group still be a Genocide? is not what word would be used?

Comment: I think the central concept of genocide is as highlighted in this excerpt from [*Convention on the Prevention and Punishment of Genocide*](http://www.preventgenocide.org/genocide/officialtext-printerfriendly.htm), outlining *Punishable Acts: The following are genocidal acts when committed as part of **a policy to destroy a group’s existence.*** For me, the difference between "indiscriminate" killing and genocide turns on the motivation. Only if the victims are an identifiable "large group" and the intention is to wipe them out ***completely*** is it truly genocide.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe in your example is not, in my opinion, genocide. Genocide is a term used to describe the killing of a *specific* group identifiable by a trait they all *share*, such as religion, instead of a trait they all *lack*.

The closest term to what you describe in your example would be xenocide. While not in common use in areas other than science fiction, where it usually applies to the killing of an alien race, at its core, its meaning is "the killing of anyone not like a specified group, or 'anyone *other*.'"

Comment: This is a useful answer. It could be improved by linking to online references that back you up.